# Finding the energy of a Lagrangian

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism

I have the following Lagrangian:

$$L=\frac{\mu}{2}\left(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot\phi^2\right)-U(r),$$

The Euler-Lagrange equations are thus:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\mu r^2\dot\phi\right)=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\mu \dot r)=\mu r\dot{\phi}^2-\frac{\partial}{\partial r}U(r).$$

Then the textbook goes to the following argument which I don't understand:

> Furthermore, given that the Lagrangian is independent of time, we have a conserved first integral
>
> \begin{align}
> E&=\dot r(\mu\dot r)+\dot\phi(\mu r^2\dot\phi)-L\\
> &=\frac{\mu}{2}\left(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\phi^2\right)+U(r).\tag{4.15}
> \end{align}

I don't understand where the first line is coming from. I know the second line is just $E = T + V$.

Answer (score 2):

That first line is the definition of the Hamiltonian

$$H=\sum_i\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i}\dot{q}_i-L,$$

where $q_i$ are the generalized coordinates, in your case $r$ and $\phi$. There are several details concerning the definition which are not relevant in this case, so let me omit them, but you can find them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics).

Using Hamiltonian equations, it can be proved that $$\frac{dH}{dt}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t},$$
which means that if the Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on time, the Hamiltonian is a constant of motion. Besides, you can see that in this case the Hamiltonian is the energy $H=E=T+U$. Again, I say "in this case" because it is not always the case that $H=E$.